# Magento 2.3.5: Showing Invalid Form key on every page

Tags: magento2, magento-enterprise, magento2-enterprise, form-key, magento2.3.5

We are facing an issue after upgrading Magento version to 2.3.5.

**Invalid form key. Please refresh the page.**

is showing on every page only on safari browser.

Comment: We are having the same issue after upgrading to Magento ver. 2.3.5-p1
Only affecting safari browser.
I've changed to developer mode with bin/magento d:m:set developer
Ran rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/*
And then bin/magento d:m:set production to recompile and clear caches
Issue still present in safari only.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I fixed this error by updating my cps_whitelist.xml file.

Unfortunately I can't say what policy fixed it.
I think it was in policy id="connect-src" for Facebook.com

https://sherocommerce.com/magento-content-security-policy/

We are having the same issue after upgrading to Magento ver. 2.3.5-p1
Only affecting safari browser.
I've changed to developer mode with
bin/magento d:m:set developer
Ran rm -rf var/di/* var/generation/* var/cache/* var/log/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/*
And then bin/magento d:m:set production
to recompile and clear caches
Issue still present in safari only.

Answer (score 0):

Try a clear browser cache and delete the cookies.

Check the Magento error log file if logged with any error.

If not work then please try to increase the value of **max_input_vars** in the **php.ini** file. By default, this value is set to 1000. You should set it to 5000 or 10000.

Also, check by removing generated, var/cache, var/page_cache, var/view_processed directories, and run below commands in case if it helps to solve the issue.

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```